# Setting Canvas background in onload function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I want to write on top of Image. So I was trying to set the background image of the canvas object using onLoad function. drawImage() works and draws on canvas but if I try to set canvas background image, it doesnt work.

This works

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  canvas.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  imageObj.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
   };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
  </script>
```

This doesnt work

```
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();
  canvas.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
  imageObj.onload = function() {
  canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+imageObj+')';
   };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
  </script>
```

Comment: I don't see why you would need to `draw` anything if you want to set the CSS `background` property? Btw, you will need to set it to `imageObj.src`…

Comment: You really can't concantenate an image object into a string and expect the style to be set. It has to be a string. You could of course do `'url('+imageObj.src+')';` but that sort of defeats the purpose of creating an image object to begin with.

Comment: thanks... what am trying to achieve is having a canvas of set width and resize its height by adjusting size of image. And then put image as a background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an object in a style, it would have to be the string only:

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var image   = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg'

canvas.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
canvas.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+image+')';
```